# Unexpected behavior when using a fixed position on a div

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, css-position, fixed

My `<body />` has a `<ion-nav-bar />` and a `<ion-nav-view />`. Within the `<ion-content />` of a `<ion-view />`, I would like to add a `<div />` which takes the whole screen's width and height (i.e. totally covers all other elements), so I added the following style:

```css
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Oddly, the top of the `<div />` does not get to the top of the screen, but to the bottom of the `<ion-nav-bar />`. Any idea why?

Here is a plunker you can play with: http://plnkr.co/edit/q2iynXaMnTZ2fGqzlJZo. You'll see that the red border does not cover the header. Have a look at the `home.html` and the `style.css` files.

I must have misunderstand something about the fixed position, I thought that width a fixed position, an element is positioned relative to the browser window. So where am I wrong? And how to make my fixed `<div />` take the whole screen?

Comment: If any parent have `position: relative/absolute`, that will be to which the absolute positoned div will adjust.

Comment: Now, as you can't remove the `transform`, you can add a `script` tag straight after your div and calc the x/y cordinates and set them negative. ... well, you can add it where ever you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, however, when you use `transform` on an ancestor a fixed position descendant is positioned relative to it.

So because this (ancestor of your fixed element):

```
<div style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);" class="scroll padding">
```

Is using `transform`, the fixed elements coordinates are relative to the size of this div. If you were to remove the transform, you would get the expected results.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other way instead of *removing the transform*? I'm afraid this could break some other working behaviors...

Comment: Unless you remove the `transform` it's not possible using fixed positioning. Unless you can remove it and then apply it to one ancestor above